# Laravel Nova: Query params empty for /nova-api/installations/relate-authorization in hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel-nova

I have defined a HasMany relationsship in my Nova resource. Nova fires two requests when trying to load the children in the parent detail view:

`1. GET /nova-api/childResources?viaResource=parentResources&viaResourceId=4711&viaRelationship=childResources&relationshipType=hasMany`

-> This correctly returns the related records.

`2. GET /nova-api/childResources/relate-authorization?viaResource=parentResources&viaResourceId=4711&viaRelationship=childResources&relationshipType=hasMany`

-> This fails with a HTTP 500 returning `Class name must be a valid object or a string`.

Digging deeper into the underlying NovaRequest, I found out that all query params are gone inside the request. This is why `viaResource` cannot be used to instantiate a class and to above error occurs.

I have no idea, what could cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out, the problem originated from an incomplete nginx configuration. I wasn’t passing the query string to PHP.